# How to make letters linked within each other in a SVG

Tags: text, logo, svg, figma

I am making a logo for an web application using Figma.

What I got so far is:

[image]

I managed to show the D linked into the P by coloring in one of the intersects of the two letters. But is there a better way to do this? Because of so many of the pencil marks, the SVG file is larger than the PNG. I am fine with using something else other then Figma.

The SVG is available here: https://gist.github.com/TalinTheDev/2aabbed4674bd85c73d9f1fe44947439

**EDIT**
Using Billy Kerr's answer, I was able to edit my image and reduce the file size (for SVG) from 23 KB to 10KB! A 56.5217% reduction! Thanks! *The gist points to the new image!*

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There is no guarantee that a vector file would be smaller in file size than a corresponding PNG.  Can you share the SVG over at SVGshare.com?  There might be something that could be done to reduce the file size if that's the problem. It's hard to tell without being able to examine the code.

Comment: @BillyKerr Really the size isn’t the problem… It’s just that if you zoom in really close, you can kind of see the bad coloring in. I tried my best but you can still see the extra colors coming outside the P/D.

Comment: you need to post the SVG. There's no way to tell what's wrong without seeing it. Sorry.

Comment: @BillyKerr It's fine. SVGShare.com was having a Over Quota error thingy so I made a gist: https://gist.github.com/TalinTheDev/2aabbed4674bd85c73d9f1fe44947439

Comment: Thanks for that. Perfect,. Now I see the problem. I've added an answer.

Comment: MODERATORS: I would like to know who is upvoting this question after 5 weeks? I got two upvotes already for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SVG there seem to be several failed attempts to paint over the orange D with various strokes. You should delete these.

[image]

Instead, it would be better to use the Pen Tool to draw a rectangular patch, remove the stroke, fill it with the same green as the P, then bend the paths using the Bend tool so the patch fits over the D.

Note: to be able to do it accurately you'll need to switch off the Snap to Pixel Grid in the preferences, if you haven't done so already, and obviously zoom in to get it right.

An example. I've highlighted the Pen and Bend tools you can use to draw the patch. You can see the fill applied, and the stroke has been removed.

[image]

Here's what it looks like without the vector paths active

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That works! Could you please take a look at the gist again and let me know from an outsider's perspective if it looks perfectly linked? Thanks again!

Comment: @TalinTheDev - looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I honestly cannot believe this was so easy!